# Amp Page does not score well on PageSpeed Insights

Tags: server, frontend, amp-html, pagespeed-insights

My Article page (https://psychology-to-go.com/what-is-stage-5-alzheimers) does not perform well on PageSpeed Insight. It only scores 54 for mobile and 67 for desktop. Even though I did the following things already:

- compressed all jpgs,
- preloaded the hero image
- used webp,
- compressed mp4 and created fallback with webm,
- minified CSS and deleted unused CSS classes,

The total blocking time is almost 1.2 seconds...
Is it maybe my server? What can I try to improve in my code that it runs faster?
The entire idea behind me coding with AMP was to have a super-fast website... Quiet the bummer...

P.S.: I have a cheap 5 Dollar server and run with laravel forge the backend. Should I consider upgrading? Could somebody maybe share their server specs, too?

Comment: did you checked your site on https://amp.dev/page-experience/ guide and https://web.dev/measure/ here is a report  https://lighthouse-dot-webdotdevsite.appspot.com//lh/html?url=https%3A%2F%2Fpsychology-to-go.com%2Fwhat-is-stage-5-alzheimers

Comment: total blocking time is to do with JavaScript execution time, nothing to do with your server. The problem is that there is over 200kb of JS being pushed down the wire (nearly 650kb uncompressed) which is an awful lot for such a simple site. The other thing that immediately jumps out is the video background - you will struggle to get a very high score with a video background. The only other thing (that could be server related) is Time To First Byte at almost 500ms! Are you generating the page dynamically rather than caching it and serving it from cache?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answering @Graham Ritchie, I thought the Video is not the cause. It has a poster which is preloaded, too... however, should I cut down on javascript?? Can this really drastically change speed? Besides, page is sort of dynamic,  I use a unique slug, which is checked in my dB with 1500 other slugs... but its laravel, meaning I use first or fail logic... should I rather code it hardwired ?? Thus not calling post from a dB via slug??? I hope this makes sense, I tried my best describing it

Answer (score 0):

Do you try [AMP Optimizer](https://github.com/ampproject/amp-toolbox-php)? Its prerender your AMP code and saved time.